# Multiple nested dictionaries within a nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

Thanks to SO I have created a desired nested dictionary with the right keys from the following DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['jake','martin','justin'], 'date': ['6/7/2021','1/1/2031','1/4/2011'], 'country':['Russia','USA','Australia'],
'city 1':['Moscow','New York','Sidney'], 'city 2':['St. Petersburg','Los Angeles','Brisbane'], 'kids':[5,3,1], 'Feature 1':['some','feature','here'], 'Feature 2':['some2','feature2','here2']})
```

that looks like this:

```
   name      country   city 1    city2           kids   Feature1   Feature2   date  
0  jake      Russia    Moscow    St. Petersburg  5       some       some2     1/1/2031
1  martin    USA       New York  Los Angeles     3       feature    feature2  4/4/2021
2  justin    Australia Sidney    Brisbane        1       here       here2     2/3/2015
```

**Eventual goal:**

to create a nested dictionary that looks like this:

`{jake: {'name':'jake', 'Russia': {'city1':'Moscow', 'city2': 'St. Petersburg'}, '5': {'Feature1':'some', 'Feature1':'some2'}, 'date': '1/1/2031'}, martin: {}}`

So my goal is to create nested dictionaries within a nested dictionary and I've tried different approaches including the use of `defaultdict` but unfortunately without a success.

Here is the code I've used to create a nested dictionary with the 1st level of nesting:

`{jake: {'name':'jake', 'country':'Russia', 'city1':'Moscow', ...}}`

```
df.set_index('name', inplace=True, drop=False)
d = df.transpose().to_dict()
```

I've also tried to create a separate dictionary and then append it but no success. Any help very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if i understood you correctly, maybe iterating over the dataframe's rows and setting the values for the dictionary is a solution:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    my_dict[row['name']] = {'name': row['name'],
                            row['country']: {'city 1':row['city 1'], 'city 2':row['city 2']},
                            'kids': row['kids'],
                            'date':row['date'], 
                            'features':[row['Feature 1'], row['Feature 2']]}

my_dict
```

Output:

```
{'jake': {'Russia': {'city 1': 'Moscow', 'city 2': 'St. Petersburg'},
  'date': '6/7/2021',
  'features': ['some', 'some2'],
  'kids': 5,
  'name': 'jake'},
 'justin': {'Australia': {'city 1': 'Sidney', 'city 2': 'Brisbane'},
  'date': '1/4/2011',
  'features': ['here', 'here2'],
  'kids': 1,
  'name': 'justin'},
 'martin': {'USA': {'city 1': 'New York', 'city 2': 'Los Angeles'},
  'date': '1/1/2031',
  'features': ['feature', 'feature2'],
  'kids': 3,
  'name': 'martin'}}
```